# How to access the instance of service object in onResume() part of an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

There is a service and activity.

Service class has one method

```
methodA().
```

Now I have binded the service in Activity and got the instance of service through service connection.

problem is I can't access the instance of service inside onResume() method

```
Public void onResume(){
forExample.  mService.methodA // is throwing null pointer exception
}
```

update: 
   This is how I created a service instance

```
class A extends Activity{
public ServiceClass mService = null; // service objecct
void onCreate(){
       Intent ServiceIntent = new Intent(this,BleWrapper.class);    
       bindService(ServiceIntent,mServiceConnection,BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
       mLeService = BLEService.getInstance();
} 
Public void onResume(){
  mService.methodA // is throwing null pointer exception
}
}
```

my Service connection is

```
public final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection= new ServiceConnection() {  
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        mService = ((BleWrapper.LocalBinder) service).getService();
)
```

Can any one please help me.

Comment: Show how have you created instance of service in activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it would throw `NullPointerException` because you have **not initialized** a service at all.

Initialize a service in `onCreate()` method, And then you can use `mService.methodA()` on `onResume()`

```
class A extends Activity{
    public ServiceClass mService = null; // service objecct

    public void onCreate(){
        mService = new ServiceClass();
    }

    public void onResume(){
        mService.methodA();
    }
}
```

**Note :** Whenever you create any object, it must be initialized before getting used.

Comment: Now i can't access the mService object in a method that is outside any of android life cycles method..

Comment: It worked Thanks. But now there is a simple method between onCreate() and onResume(). I can't access the service object there. That method Is called as soon as onClick is performed. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: @DineshRavi There's no information provided regarding to that issue, you can post a new question if you have any query. You could upvote and accept my answer if it helped you,

Answer (score 1):

You can get the instance of that service somewhere else in your Activity. The result can be given to the `onResume()` method.